# PHP paid-for support script?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script

I'm looking for a support system/helpdesk where users are required to pay for every question they have asked. Can anybody recommend me a good one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't name one off the top of my head but there are quite a few in the ['support' section at hotscripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/search/php/helpdesk)